# Symmetries in physics

Tags: symmetry, group-theory, field-theory, group-representations

Can you explain me some of the mathematical details of such concept as symmetries?
In physics, we have some manifold, and fields are functions on this manifold.

*On the one hand*, we have **symmetries of fields**: for example, in the simplest case of spontaneous symmetry breaking group $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ acts on the algebra of functions on the manifold. But coordinates remain untouched.

*On the other hand*, there are **spatial symmetries** in physics, for example Poincare symmetry. In this case, as I understand, Poincare group acts on our manifold (in the mathematical sense: [Group action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action)) and **somehow induces an action** on the algebra of fields (How? Can you explain this construction strictly?).

Also we can consider a situation with both kinds of symmetry:

$$
S=\int \left[\left(\partial_{a} \phi_{1} \right)^{2}+ \left(\partial_{a} \phi_{2} \right)^{2}+ \frac{m^2 \phi_{1}^{2}}{2} + \frac{m^2 \phi_{2}^{2}}{2}\right]
$$

In this case we have internal symmetry group $O(2)$: $S[\phi(x)]=S[M\phi(x)]$, $M^{T}M=1$.
It was said to me that in this case physicists write $P\otimes O(2)$, where $P$ is Poincare group, $O(2)$ is acting only on fields, but Poincare group on both space manifold and fields.

**So my questions are:**

**What is the relation between these symmetries and what is the exact construction here? How group acting on space manifold induces action on fields?**

Can you explain this strictly in mathematical sense?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19751/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23936/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a theory of fields $\phi:M\to T$ where $M$ is a manifold, and $T$ is a set.  In physics, $T$ is often either a vector space or a manifold.  We call $M$ the **domain** of the theory, and we call $T$ the **target space**. of the theory.  We call a function from $M$ to $T$ a **field configuration**, and the set of all field configurations is denoted $\mathcal F$.

Let's consider two situations:

**Case 1.** Let groups $G_M$ and $G_T$ be given.  Let $\rho_M$ be an action of $G_M$ on $M$, and let $\rho_T$ be an action of $G_T$ on $T$, then there is a "natural" action of $\rho_\mathcal F$ of $G_M\times G_T$ on $\mathcal F$ given by
\begin{align}
  \rho_\mathcal F(g_M, g_T)(\phi)(x) = \rho_T(g_T)\Big(\phi\big(\rho_M(g_M)^{-1}(x)\big)\Big)
\end{align}
I'll leave it to you to prove that this is a group action.

**Case 2.** Let a groups $G$ be given.  Let $\rho_M$ be an action of $G$ on $M$, and let $\rho_T$ be an action of $G$ on $T$, then there is a "natural" action of $\rho_\mathcal F$ of $G$ on $\mathcal F$ given by
\begin{align}
  \rho_\mathcal F(g)(\phi)(x) = \rho_T(g)\Big(\phi\big(\rho_M(g)^{-1}(x)\big)\Big)
\end{align}
I'll leave it to you to prove that this is in fact a group action.

Now, let us phrase your question in the following way:

> In either of the above cases, is their a sense in which $\rho_M$ induces $\rho_T$?

The answer, as far as I am aware, is that it depends on the context and on what you mean by "induced."  Let's consider the example you give in your statement of the question.

**Example.** An $\mathrm{O}(2)$ vector field on $\mathbb R^{3,1}$.

We have
\begin{align}
  M = \mathbb R^{3,1}, \qquad T = \mathbb R^2, \qquad G_M = \mathrm{P}(3,1), \qquad G_T = \mathrm{O}(2)
\end{align}
where $\mathrm{P}(3,1)$ is the Poincare group in four dimensions.  In this case, one often takes $\rho_M$ and $\rho_T$ to be
\begin{align}
  \rho_M(\Lambda,a)(x) = \Lambda x+a, \qquad \rho_T(R)(v) = Rv
\end{align}
Notice that this falls under Case 1 above.  In this case, there is no "canonical" relationship (as far as I am aware) between the Poincare group and $\mathrm{O}(2)$, so there is no canonical sense in which $\rho_M$ induces $\rho_T$.

However, consider the following example:

**Example.**  An $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ $2$-tensor field on $\mathbb R^{3}$.

We have
\begin{align}
  M = \mathbb R^{3}, \qquad T = T_2(\mathbb R^3), \qquad G = \mathrm{SO}(3)
\end{align}
where $T_2(\mathbb R^3)$ is the vector space of $2$-tensors on $\mathbb R^3$.  Then there is a natural action of $G$ on $M$ given by
\begin{align}
  \rho_M(R)x = Rx
\end{align}
Since $2$-tensors on $\mathbb R^3$ can be described as bilinear maps functions $S:\mathbb R^3\times \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$, there is also a natural action of $G$ on $T$ given by
\begin{align}
  \rho_T(S)(x_1, x_2) = S(R^{-1}x_1, R^{-1} x_2)
\end{align}
which can also be written as
\begin{align}
  \rho_T(S)(x_1, x_2) = S(\rho_M(R)^{-1}x_1, \rho_M(R)^{-1} x_2)
\end{align}
so, in this case, there is a sense in which $\rho_M$ has induced $\rho_T$.